# javascript clone textfield with a string added

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange, copy-paste, cloning

I have a form containing 4 text fields. JS is making sure that firstname, lastname and fullname are filled in effectively... but I want the field picture file to contain the fullname value with the extension .jpg. Allowing me to change the picture file field manually when there is a need for it.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="form">

      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" />
      <hr>

      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" />
      <hr>


      <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fullname" />

      <label for="picturefile">picture file</label>
      <input type="text" id="picturefile" />
    </form>
```

javascript code

```
jQuery(document).ready(UserInfoCtrl);
    function UserInfoCtrl($) 
        {
          var self = this;

          var form = $('#form');
          var fname = $('#fname');
          var lname = $('#lname');
          var fullname = $('#fullname');

          self.updateFirstName = function(firstName) {
            var _lname = lname.val() || (fullname.val() || '').trim().split(' ').pop(); 
            fullname.val(firstName + ' ' + _lname);
          };

          self.updateLastName = function(lastName) {
            var _fname = fname.val() || (fullname.val() || '').trim().split(' ').shift(); 
            fullname.val(_fname + ' ' + lastName);
          };

          self.updateFullName = function(fullName) {
            var _fullname = (fullName || '').trim().split(' ');

            fname.val((_fullname[0] || ''));
            lname.val((_fullname[1] || ''));
          };

          self.onFieldChange = function(e) {
            switch(this.id) {
              case 'fname':
                self.updateFirstName(this.value);
                break;

              case 'lname':
                self.updateLastName(this.value);
                break;

              case 'fullname':
                self.updateFullName(this.value);
                break;
            }
          };

          fname.add(lname).add(fullname).change(self.onFieldChange);

          form.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          });
        }
```

Comment: Is the user allowed to change the extension?

Comment: Should a change to the picture file propagate those changes back to the first/last name, like you do with fullname?

Comment: Why no answers to these questions for clarification?

Comment: Yes the user is allowed to change the extension. No propagation is required. A user without the JS adds would had to put in the firstname, then lastname, then the fullname and last also the picture...The JS adds makes this form easier to fill in.

Comment: So what if the user has all filled in, then changes the picturefile input, and then makes a correction to the first name?  Should the picturefile be updated automatically, thereby forgetting the changes made manually to it? Or did you have another behaviour in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something like that

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(UserInfoCtrl);
    function UserInfoCtrl($) 
        {
          var self = this;

          var form = $('#form');
          var fname = $('#fname');
          var lname = $('#lname');
          var fullname = $('#fullname');

          self.updateFirstName = function(firstName) {
            var _lname = lname.val() || (fullname.val() || '').trim().split(' ').pop(); 
            fullname.val(firstName + ' ' + _lname);
            UpdateImage();
          };

          self.updateLastName = function(lastName) {
            var _fname = fname.val() || (fullname.val() || '').trim().split(' ').shift(); 
            fullname.val(_fname + ' ' + lastName);
            UpdateImage();
          };

          self.updateFullName = function(fullName) {
            var _fullname = (fullName || '').trim().split(' ');

            fname.val((_fullname[0] || ''));
            lname.val((_fullname[1] || ''));
          };

          self.onFieldChange = function(e) {
            switch(this.id) {
              case 'fname':
                self.updateFirstName(this.value);
                break;

              case 'lname':
                self.updateLastName(this.value);
                break;

              case 'fullname':
                self.updateFullName(this.value);

                break;
            }
          };
          function UpdateImage(){
             $('#picturefile').val(jQuery('#fullname').val() + ".jpg"); 
          }



          fname.add(lname).add(fullname).change(self.onFieldChange);

          form.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          });
        }
</script>
```